# Cocos2d: How Can I Make a Small Scrollable & Customisable List Like Doodle Jump's Leaderboard

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone, customization

Doodle jump have a great scrolling list here and I'd really like to make my own.

I love the sunken look and feel this has... How is it done?

Where Can I start, what is the object I need to create?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, misread the title. This probably doesn't apply to Cocos2d.

That seems to be a quite standard [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

So you can create a standard [`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and then put the `UITableView`inside it. `UITableView` inherits from `UIView`, so you can set the frame like you'd do with any UIView (also add shadows etc.). Then you'll just need to create a custom [`UITableViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) and [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) and assign them to the `UITableView`.

If you're not familiar with Table Views, check out the [Table View Programming Guide by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

Comment: ok grate, I'll check this out try it anyway and let you know...
I assumed that the developer used cocos2d to make it or something similar, so thought that the UI element would be accessible by me somehow?
In the meantime, if anyone has any ideas, please let me know!

Comment: This doesn't appear work at all for me...
I'm hoping someone will see doodle jump above, and give me what I'm looking for.... thanks